# Hive and mongodb connector

Tags: mongodb, hive

How can write json file(hive output) to mongodb,Are there any exsisting udfs which I can use or should I use mongodb hadoop connector for this, which is the best way to do this.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can you [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) from Elastic to create this pipeline. Read files with JSON input plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html and write to database with MongoDB output plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-mongodb.html